# Change base urls and backend catalog not loading

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0, base-url

After changing the base urls into database core_config_data, clear cache, reindex, if I go to my domain works fine but if I go to my admin site when I push over catalog the page not loading

[image: catalog not loading]

It is showing the loading icon infinitely. What can I do?

**The solution was to clean the browser cache :-)**

Comment: Do you try to redeploy static files and enable  "sign static file"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I redeploy static files, but continues without load

Comment: Try the [`magento setup:store-config:set`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-store.html) command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve but the solution was to clean the browser cache :-)